# Is Rally TimeEntryValue query available in WSAPI?

Tags: rally

Several examples in REST. Not interested in REST. Please provide WSAPI example.

Beginning to wonder if TimeEntryValue was implemented in WSAPI.

Comment: Still waiting to see example of js using wsapi from TimeEntryValue to get the 'Hours'

Answer (score 0):

TimeEntryValue is exposed via WSAPI.  You can find it in the docs here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Do you have a specific question around how to use it?

Comment: Was interested in javascript to get the Hours from TimeEntryItem then TimeEntryValue for the WSAPI. Like the REST API code in the question "How to extract Timesheet data using Rally WS API?"

Comment: The question you mentioned is using the node.js toolkit.  What language and/or toolkit are you trying to use?